# Trouble shooting warning message the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Tags: r, loops, warnings

I am trying to run the code below. I am struggling with understanding the 50+ error messages. I know that this code has worked for others in the past. I double checked my data and I have no missing values for the variables in the HAZ and WAZ calculation, but there are missing values in the bcattlescreen, dcattlescreen, etc. What might be the issue?

```
      for(i in 1:length(TCDATA)){TCDATA$HAZ <- getWGS(sexObserved = TCDATA$sex_anthro, firstPart = TCDATA$child_height_anthro, secondPart = TCDATA$child_agein_months_anthro, index = "hfa") 
    + TCDATA$WAZ <- getWGS(sexObserved = TCDATA$sex_anthro, firstPart = TCDATA$child_weight_anthro, secondPart = TCDATA$child_agein_months_anthro, index = "wfa")
    +     TCDATA$HighEdMom[TCDATA$mother_schooling == 3 | TCDATA$mother_schooling == 4] <- 1 
    +     TCDATA$Stunted[TCDATA$HAZ < -2] <- 1 
    + }
```

There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Warning messages:

1. In if (is.na(sexObserved) | is.na(firstPart) | is.na(secondPart)) { ... :
     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2. In sex == sexObserved :
     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3. In given == secondPart :
     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
4. In if (z > 3) { ... :
     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Answer (score 0):

When you evaluate is.na(sexObserved) you will get a vector of TRUE, FALSE, TRUE or something like that depending on whether or not there are any NA values. However, when you put that in an `if` statement then R is telling you its only going to take the first value because if statements don't act on vectors. All you need to do is wrap your is.na(sexObserved) inside and all() function. all(is.na(sexObserved) this will return TRUE only if all the values are NA or FALSE if all the values are false.

Comment: I am getting error message object 'sexObserved' not found after running: all(is.na(sexObserved), for(i in 1:length(TCDATA)){TCDATA$HAZ <- getWGS(sexObserved = TCDATA$sex_anthro, firstPart = TCDATA$child_height_anthro, secondPart = TCDATA$child_agein_months_anthro, index = "hfa") 
+ TCDATA$WAZ <- getWGS(sexObserved = TCDATA$sex_anthro, firstPart = TCDATA$child_weight_anthro, secondPart = TCDATA$child_agein_months_anthro, index = "wfa")
+     TCDATA$HighEdMom[TCDATA$mother_schooling == 3 | TCDATA$mother_schooling == 4] <- 1 
+     TCDATA$Stunted[TCDATA$HAZ < -2] <- 1 
+ })